# Mouse over hover not working using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a incorporated a jQuery mouse over hover function on my site ([click here and scroll down to images with coloured blocks](http://www.lybstore.com/index.php)). I have noticed the hover state image is not visible although I have played around with the Z-index. What is causing this issue?

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
<div class="shirt-block" style="background:#333334;">
    <figure>
        <img class="shirt col-img-inner" src="img/B0713011sf2.jpg" alt="alt"/>
    </figure>
</div>

.shirt-block {
    width:47%;
    float:left;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    margin-left:2%;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:600px;
    position:relative;
}

.shirt-block > figure { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:100%; }


.shirt-sizer { width:100%; /* same as figure width */ }

.shirt {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

.shirt-hover {
    background:url(http://www.lybstore.com/img/home-hover-bg.png);
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0;
}


$('figure').append('<div class="shirt-hover"/>');

var $sizer = $("<img/>",  {src:"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8AAABkCAMAAADXLxypAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACBJREFUeNrtwTEBAAAAwiD7p14Hb2AAAAAAAAAAAABcAiWAAAEKyWyqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"}).addClass("shirt-sizer");

$('.shirt-block').append($sizer);

$('.shirt-hover').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},200);
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0},200);
});
```

Comment: Your site has some JS that seems to be for a jquery hover event, but it is commented out.  Could you please verify and add the script to the post?

Comment: @Fallexe not sure if it was you that downgraded me, but the reason it was commented out is bcos i am testing the answers given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:  >> instead of: `$('.shirt-hover').hover(...)` <<

```
$('.shirt-block img').mouseenter(function(){
    var $imgHover = $(this).next('.shirt-hover');
    $imgHover.width($(this).width()).height($(this).height()).stop().animate({opacity:1},200);
});
 $('.shirt-hover').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0},200,function(){$(this).height(0)});
});
```

And remove: `z-index:100;`  in CSS for `.shirt-hover` it is useless and make it pass over bottom div.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
.shirt-hover {
```

with

```
.shirt:hover {
```

So it should be like this

```
.shirt:hover {
      background:url(http://www.lybstore.com/img/home-hover-bg.png);
      background-size:cover;
      position:absolute;
      top:0; right:0;
      z-index:100;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      opacity:0;
  }
```

Comment: Sure but doing that does not show the hover image, it just shows the div background??

Comment: @NewBoy So, could you please remove :hover pseudo class to your css to let us test what going on?

Comment: @Gautam3164 the shirt's hove background should be http://www.lybstore.com/img/home-hover-bg.png

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo selectors work like this : `.shirt:hover` , `.shirt-hover` could never work.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo selectors **always** use a colon (**:**), **never** a dash (**-**). Therefore, `shirt:hover` will work as a replacement.

Instead of jQuery's `.hover`, you could use `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`.